# Are there any Monaco editors that offer Roblox lua syntax highlighting?

Tags: lua, roblox

The default lua doesn't work that well, like with

```
while wait() do
```

Only the if then statements work for that, Other statements like

```
Game:GetService("")
```

Are quite hard to find with coloring like roblox's ide: like Game would be blue and GetService would be light yellow.
(Also one that works with visual studio c# web browser)

Comment: for your example of the highlighting for `Game.GetService` how does that work for any table? such as `someTable.someValue` or `someTable.someNested.someValue`

Comment: You're asking for syntax highlighting / linter for your text-editor / IDE?  gEdit, Atom, Midnight Commander, Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

Rojo is a tool that can connect to external text editors such as VS Code  and allows you to use syntax highlighting for LuaU: https://rojo.space/docs/